# owl carousel on click active class not displayed on same page

Tags: php, jquery, html, owl-carousel

Here i write the code for display the active class on same page.

```
            <?php 
            $j = 0;
            $n = '';
            foreach($model2 as $value)
            {   
            $j++;
            //$id = $value['intBlogId'];

            $image = $value['varImage'];
            $title = $value['varTitle'];
            $link = $value['varLink'];
            $blog_id = $value['intBlogId'];

            $actcls = '';

            if($blog_id == $blogid) {
            $actcls = 'curactive';
            $n = $j;
            }

            ?>
            <div class="item <?php echo $actcls; ?>" id="item_<?php echo $blog_id; ?>"><a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('blog_detail?blogid=').$blog_id; ?>">
            <span class="left_blog">
            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="images" class="img-responsive" /></span>
            <span class="right_blog"><span class="heading_blog"><?php if(strlen(nl2br($title)) > 39 ) echo substr(strip_tags(nl2br($title)),0,38).".."; else echo nl2br($title); ?></span><span id="link" ><?php if(strlen(nl2br($link)) > 50 ) echo substr(strip_tags(nl2br($link)),0,49).".."; else echo nl2br($link); ?></span></span>
            </a></div>
            <?php }  ?>
            </div>
            <div class="customNavigation">
            <a class="btn prev">Previous</a>
            <a class="btn next">Next</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div style="position:relative; height:100vh;" id ="frame">
            <iframe id="asa" width="100%" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; border: none;" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="<?php echo $url; ?>"></iframe>
            </div>
```

The above mentioned code displayed the slider

The script codes are:

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var carousel = $("#listing_blog_sec"); 
            carousel.trigger('owl.jumpTo', <?php echo @$GLOBALS['MyVar']; ?>)
            });
            </script>
```

In the above code the if i click the slider no 4 in the page after the page refresh it shows in the slider no 5 but i scroll the slider the slider 4 will be in active.

I want this (
If i click the slider no 6 after the page refresh the slider no 6 only active on same page )

Kindly help me to fix this

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var carousel = $("#listing_blog_sec"); 
            carousel.trigger('owl.jumpTo', <?php echo @$GLOBALS['MyVar']-1; ?>)
            });
            </script>
```

Finally it works fine